# javascript class change to asp:button control not available on server side

Tags: c#, javascript

So I have looked for days for a solution online to this, and I've tried different ways of doing this, but can't seem to find a complete solution.  So please HELP!

I  have a form that a user is filling out online.  At one point in the form, they select keywords they want to associate with their input.  I have created a table layout of buttons with each keyword in a button.

```
<asp:Button 
    ID="button1" 
    Text="Kid Friendly" 
    CssClass="button_off"  
    runat="server" 
    onclientclick="change_select(this);" 
    OnClick="return false;" >
</asp:Button>
<br />
<asp:Button 
    ID="button2" 
    Text="Romantic" 
    CssClass="button_off"  
    runat="server" 
    onclientclick="change_select(this);" 
    OnClick="return false;" >
</asp:Button>
<br />
```

..and so on. 
The buttons have a background of blue.  If a user clicks on a button, it runs javascript to change the class of the button, which changes the background to green.

```
function change_select(objs)
{
    var mydoc = objs.className;
    if (mydoc == "button_off") 
    {
        objs.className = "button_on";
        document.getElementById("button1").setAttribute("SkinID", "3");
    }
    else 
    {
        objs.className = "button_off";
    }
}
```

Then at the bottom, I have a button to submit the info:

```
 <asp:Button ID="button4" Text="Verify"  runat="server" onclick="verify" >
```

When I test the page, clicking on the buttons changes the class and the backgrounds change back and forth, but when I try to grab the class of each element on the server side, it always comes back as "button_off".

```
protected void verify(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myValue = button1.CssClass.ToString();
    string myInfo = "<h3>Your buttons</h3><p>Here is the class: " + myValue;

    myResults.InnerHtml = myInfo.ToString()
}
```

How can the C# on the server side get that the user has changed the class?  I did try changing these to HTML elements Kid Friendly, but I couldn't figure out how to reference the HTML element on the Server side. I found posts on areas with code to do that (referencing HTMLElement), but that code never worked on my development machine.

Yes, I could just make the keywords labels and add checkboxes next to each one, but that is so boring; I was trying to create a more interesting interface here.  Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the css class in a hidden field on submit.

Comment: When the page posts back because of the Button Click event, the elements will revert to their normal CssClass state. So you gotta use something else to store that new class. A hidden field, as suggested, or a cookie/session/whatever else.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that too.  Adding a hidden field for each button element and storing the value there, but that seems like a lot of code.  Some told me to look at jquery's button widget that makes checkboxes look like buttons. I think that will probably be my answer.